# RecyclerView findViewHolderForAdapterPosition returns sometimes null

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

What I'm trying to do is make a video full screen from RecyclerView and while the video is playing, on pressing the minimize button to put it back into the list. Note that the state of the video is still on play after I minimize it.

Sometimes I get null object from position using .findViewHolderForAdapterPosition

My code:

```
        LinearLayout mAdapterRow = null;

        mAdapterRow = (LinearLayout) ((ViewHolder_Article_Video) mList.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(mVideoPosition)).itemView;


            if (mAdapterRow instanceof ViewGroup) {

                ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) nVideoFullScreenLayout.getChildAt(0);
                if (v.getParent() != null )
                    ((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).removeView(v); // <- fix


            ((ViewGroup) mAdapterRow).addView(v);


                ((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.mFullScreen)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.mExitFullScreen)).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                nVideoFullScreenLayout.removeAllViews();
                nVideoFullScreenLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (nVideoFullScreenLayout.getParent() != null)
                    ((ViewGroup) nVideoFullScreenLayout.getParent()).removeView(nVideoFullScreenLayout);

                View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
                // Hide the status bar.
                int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
                decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

                mHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

                mVideoFullScreen = false;

            } else {
                Log.d("dasdasdas","remove nu: "+ mAdapterRow.getTag());

            }
```

Previously.
When I make the full screen video layout, I'm taking the layout with the video instance from inside the list(RecyclerView) and put it in a new dynamic LinearLayout with the MATCH_PARENT params and set SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE.

Now the idea was to take the layout with the video instance (full screen) that is over the RecyclerView and put it back into his position.

For some reason findViewHolderForAdapterPosition doesn't always return the layout at the position of where I got the video in the first place.

Also I can see the item at position in list data adapter is not null.

[image]

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution that works for me. (this helped https://www.creospiders.com/2016/04/how-to-access-each-view-of-item-by.html , better than a post delay)

Setted the full screen layout on GONE at the beginning of the method so I can have no other view over the reycler, used getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener on recycler list to wait for the views to build and setted a boolean value that allows or not to cycle my view in onBindViewHolder (in case the video layout is at limit of being out of screen)

```
            nVideoFullScreenLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        // Hide the status bar.
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        mHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        mVideoFullScreen = false;
        mAdapter.setCyclingVideoItem(false);

        final LinearLayout[] mAdapterRow = {null};


            mList.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    mList.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    mAdapterRow[0] = (LinearLayout) ((ViewHolder_Article_Video) mList.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(mVideoPosition)).itemView;

                    setAndCleanLayouts(mAdapterRow[0]);
                    mAdapter.setCyclingVideoItem(true);
                }
            });
```